# hyperlink is not shown on the website while using nodejs to create a simple website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
function templateHTML(title, list, body){
    return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>WEB1 - ${title}</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><a href='/'>WEB</a></h1>
        ${list}
        <a href = '/create'>create</a>
        ${body}
    </body>
    </html>
    `;
}
```

This is the function that I created in the process of creating a simple website using nodejs. I don't know why but the 'create' part below my list is not shown in the website although there seems to be nothing wrong. What's the problem?

I tried adding just simple lines like `<h2>...</h2>` and even those lines were not shown in the website.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a end point and call your method in that. Like below

   app.get('', (req, res) => {

   ```
       const html = templateHTML(title, list, body);
       res.send(html);
      })
   ```
2. call above end point from your node js application. IT will invoke your method details and HTML will get render on browser.

http://localhost:YouportNumber/